# Computing result over batches while caching an expensive operation

Tags: tensorflow

I'm interested in running the same computational graph for many different batches, passed using a `feed_dict`. However, the graph contains a single very expensive operation, which remains constant for all batches. I would like to find a solution that does not require recomputing this expensive operation.

Currently, I have only found suggestions involving [`Session.partial_run()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/672). However, it seems that you cannot pass re-run the same sub-graph for different `feed_dict`s. [This is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142977/tensorflow-partial-run-must-run-setup-before-performing-partial-runs-desp), where the code follows pretty much exactly what I want to do.

Is there any way of re-running for multiple batches, without re-computing an unchanging and expensive part of the graph?