# Tensorflow Partial Run on Golang (RNN states)

Tags: tensorflow, go, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have a GRU RNN text generation model that I imported as protobuf in Golang.

```
model, err := tf.LoadSavedModel("poetryModel", []string{"goTag"}, nil)
```

Similar to [the code from this Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/text_generation#the_prediction_loop), I am running a prediction loop:

```
for len(generated_text) < 1000 {
    result, err := model.Session.Run(
            map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
                model.Graph.Operation("inputLayer_input").Output(0): tensor,
            },
            []tf.Output{
                model.Graph.Operation("outputLayer/add").Output(0),
            },
            nil,
        )
    ...}
```

However, this implementation discards all intermediate states after every loop which results in bad generated text.
I tried using [Partial Run](https://godoc.org/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go#PartialRun), but it threw an error at the second Run:

```
pr, err := model.Session.NewPartialRun(
    []tf.Output{ model.Graph.Operation("inputLayer_input").Output(0), },
    []tf.Output{ model.Graph.Operation("outputLayer/add").Output(0), },
    []*tf.Operation{ model.Graph.Operation("outputLayer/add") },
)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

...

result, err := pr.Run(
        map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
            model.Graph.Operation("inputLayer_input").Output(0): tensor,
        },
        []tf.Output{
            model.Graph.Operation("outputLayer/add").Output(0),
        },
        nil,
    )
```

`Error running the session with input, err: Must run 'setup' before performing partial runs!`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142977/tensorflow-partial-run-must-run-setup-before-performing-partial-runs-desp) is similar to this one, but in Python. Also, there is no documentation of a setup function in Go.
I am new to working directly with the TF computation graph and Golang, so any help is appreciated.